# bootstrap modal form-inline won't "inline" buttons

Tags: bootstrap-modal

i'm really stuck with this problem. Created the next modal .form-inline but the cancel button stays out of the inline, this is the code:

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-inline">

                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control-input-sm text-center" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control-input-sm text-center" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
                <input type="checkbox"><span style="color:#9d9797">Remember me</span>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign In</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                   data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The picture of it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default input max-width is 280px, you can define a class to decrease it, such as

```
<style>
    .input-short {
        max-width: 130px !important;
    }
</style>
```

then apply it to the input textboxes

```
<input type="email" class="form-control input-short" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

This should give you what you want (adjust the max-width accordingly).

Comment: "modal-lg" makes it too large and "-md" is too short, i appreciate your answer. I like the horizontal form, however i'd like to know why the above doesn't add the 'cancel' button in the inline or if there's a way to make the form smaller without fixing it.